# Converting "My travel ban was lifted" to present tense

Tags: present-tense

I'm a English learner, and I'm trying to convert the following sentence to present tense.

> My travel ban was lifted.

When we convert this to present tense, is the following correct?

> My travel ban gets lifted.

Comment: My travel ban is being lifted.

Comment: My travel ban has been lifted.

Comment: The sentence 'My travel ban was lifted' is a passive construction. A simple conversion from 'was' to 'is' yields  'My travel ban is lifted'. But although 'The window was broken' converts readily to 'The window is broken', almost always with a stative sense (contrast punctive 'Gayle lofts the ball out of the ground ... it's heading towards a shop window ... the window is broken' the stative sense is unidiomatic with  'My travel ban is lifted'. Killing Time and Ram give what are the most likely/idiomatic 'transfers to current time' answers. But if this is a test question ... who knows what goes?